# How can I create a column name that is an age range '18-49' in MYSQL

Tags: mysql

I just need to create a table with column names that are age ranges, but when I add a - sign it returns an error. What I need to have is like this:

```
+------------+
| ages_0-4   |
+------------+
| Tim        |
+------------+
| Bobby      |
+------------+
| Jim        |
+------------+
```

The column name has an age range '0-4' it returns error when I try this.

The query I'm trying to run:

```
create table tested (0-4_tested varchar(255));
```

I wasn't able to find anything on the internet so I've come here.

Comment: Please add the query you have. NB a minus in an identifier is seen as an arithmetic operator in mysql , if in a column name you need to enclose the entire name in backticks - best not use minus in column names at all and the create table is syntactically incorrect.

Comment: Please review https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/identifiers.html

Comment: To be honest this looks like the kind of data a query or temptable should return, not an actual physical table in your database.

Comment: @P.Salmon Your pry right, maybe I'll just ditch the minus sign altogether and go with something slightly different, but if there is a solution to this I would really appreciate an answer. Thanks

Comment: @P.Salman the backticks did the trick thanks for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can skip such character using "`"

```
create table tested (`0-4_tested` varchar(255));
```